# Some extra space in references IEEE

Tags: spacing, bibtex, ieeetran

I have write this code (a simple citation):

```
\noindent to an acceptable level of approximation. Alternatively, some authors~\cite{roussas1997course} simply require that:
```

And used this command, for the references:

```
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{../bib}
```

The citation is this (in the figure, the n. 20):

```
@book{roussas1997course,
  title={A course in mathematical statistics},
  edition={2},
  author={Roussas, George G},
  year={1997},
  pages = {397},
  publisher={Academic Press}
}
```

Here are the result:

[image: In red, I have underline the unwanted space]

This happens when I use `@book` in the references, but I do not know why.

Thank you in advances.

Comment: are you not using bibtex? (the question is tagged biblatex, which is a different system)

Comment: It seems to be a design choice in `IEEEtran.bst`, that uses the `large.space` function in those cases; specifically, it uses `large.space` before the publisher's data.

Comment: I have used \noindent only because this is paragraph after an equation that haven't a full stop.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni Then just put it after the equation with no empty line inbetween, and it'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you @david-carlisle, I use BibTeX and I have indicated a wrong tag. I see that now is right, sorry.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni You are welcome. In general, remember that there is no empty line in the code between the equation and the text _that belongs to the same paragraph_. This particularly means that there is never an empty line before an equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of `IEEEtran.bst`:

```
% The more flexible and complex design used here was motivated in part by
% IEEE's rather unusual bibliography style. For example, IEEE ends the
% previous field item with a period and large space prior to the publisher
% address; the @electronic entry types use periods as inter-item punctuation
% rather than the commas used by the other entry types; and URLs are never
% followed by periods even though they are the last item in the entry.
% Although it is possible to accommodate these features with the conventional
% output state system, the seemingly endless exceptions make for convoluted,
% unreliable and difficult to maintain code.
```

Indeed, before adding the publisher data, the `IEEEtran.bst` program applies the function `large.space` that's defined as

```
FUNCTION {large.space} { "\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax " }
```

So it's “by design”.

Comment: I have found this line (262) in `IEEEtrans.bst`, which explains the extra spaces. But I use (in my directory) only the `IEEEtrans.cls`. This document isn't a proceeding, but only a thesys. I use `IEEEtrans.cls` in the references for having a homogeneous layout.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni This is independent of the class: it's due just to `IEEEtran.bst`.